# Will this new drive make a significant faster speed?

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I put my operating system on my fast drive or my slow drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/212574/should-i-put-my-operating-system-on-my-fast-drive-or-my-slow-drive)

I just check the spec of my new drive and old drive, currently I am using the old drive as OS, here is the comparison:

old: 320GB, 7200rpm, 16mb cache
new: 1TB, 7200rpm, 32mb cache

If I reinstall the OS with the new drive, will I feel a significant boost of speed?

And if I don't do that, Let say:

Scenario 1: I use the new drive to store some video only, then I play these movie, they are reading from the new drive, but does the old drive matters?  Because the old drive are the OS.

Scenario 2: I use the new drive to install games only, then I play these games, they are reading from the new drive, but does the old drive matters?  Because the old drive are the OS.

Comment: If your old question about drive speed was closed as a duplicate, why do you post one again? It's not entirely the same question - but still hard to answer because it depends on so many factors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I put my operating system on my fast drive or my slow drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/212574/should-i-put-my-operating-system-on-my-fast-drive-or-my-slow-drive), and another [related question](http://superuser.com/questions/237346/ssd-as-os-drive-or-critical-program-drive), and [another related one](http://superuser.com/questions/9224/running-os-off-a-dedicated-hard-drive), and maybe [that one too](http://superuser.com/questions/60524/how-do-multiple-hard-drives-speed-up-pc-performance)

Comment: and [another one](http://superuser.com/questions/134928/hard-drive-placement)

Comment: why you insist to close my question because the other question are "similar" to my post? The specs are different, and the cases are just similar, which give much less comparison.

Comment: I don't insist on anything, it's for the community to decide. Yes, your specs are maybe a bit different, but you don't even say which hardware exactly you have, so that makes it difficult to answer accordingly. If you take a look at the answers in the linked questions, they are very generic and I think you will find most of them helpful to answer your question.

Comment: @gunbuster363: This has been answered a lot of times earlier and it really is subjective and argumentative, as we don't know what "significant" is for you and a lot of factors play a role here. Even if you were to give the entire technical specifications we still can't give a precise answer other than to say "there will be an increase in speed but we can't say by how much, it is something that you need to analyze for yourself"...

Answer (score 1):

It will make a difference, but not one that you'll notice since the speed of both drives are the same. The cache is larger and will make a difference but not a huge one.

In scenario one, the movies will use the speed from the new drive, the OS Drive will just use the old drive since it's only on the disk.

Scenario two, the games will have the same effect as on scenario one.

If you want a noticeable speed boost I would've gone for:

- SSD for OS and selected programs.
- 7200rpm, 32MB Cache for data

Comment: Or a 10,0000rpm drive. Slower than an SSD, but so very much faster than a 7200rpm, no matter the cache, and cheaper than the SSD usually too.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience I can say that going from an old 250GB drive to a 1TB drive resulting in a performance boost, for me at least.

In theory you *should* get a performance increase as the 1TB drive has a much higher data density than the 320GB drive and so raw data transfer speeds from the drive should be higher.

Doing a couple of benchmarks I found that my 250GB drive was capable of around 50-60MiB/s data transfer while the 1TB managed about 100MiB/s.  This may or may not be a noticeable boost, it depends on how you use your system..

As always though this depends on your old and new drive types, a "budget" 1TB drive may not be as fast as a Western Digital "Raptor" 250GB drive...

Comment: The new drive might also have a better seek speed (purely because its a newer model), which would have a positive effect on anything that does lots of smaller read/writes, for example booting the OS.

Comment: I can also second the increased speed going from a smaller drive to larger (provided the RPM is the same), I have a 640GB drive that maxes out at about 100MB/s read, while a 1.5TB drive hits about 125MB/s. For scenarios 1 and 2, the only time there is a dependance on the old drive is when the applications first start, as OS stuff must be loaded (video decoders, 3D graphics drivers).